# Aptana Studio 3 - remove highlight (frame) on new HTML block

Tags: html, coding-style, syntax-highlighting, aptana, aptana3

I am desperately searching for a way to remove absolutely annoying highlight / frame on new HTML blocks when you code in Aptana Studio 3.

Here's an example:
[image]

This brown bordered ugliness **on every single row** is completely cluttering the view on what you have just coded. You have to defocus the block and go back to remove it. I searched through the settings several times with no avail. I am looking for a way to remove this for a looong time (maybe since Aptana 2)...

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, that is the HTML Tag Pair Occurences preference. You can change its apprearance (make it invisible?) under `Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors > Annotations > HTML Tag Pair Occurences`. This will also affect the highlighting on existing code however. When you click inside an existing tag pair, they will be highlighted based on this same setting.

Comment: You are right. This is the setting that influences it. It is not exactly what I was looking for (I don't want to lose highlight of tag pairs) but at least I changed it to less obtrusive color. Thank you.